# mongorestore from standalone to replicaset

Tags: mongodb

I have dumped a standalone mongo database (14Gb big) running on the default port as follows:

```
mongodump --username <username> --password <password> --db <dbname>
```

and I am trying to restore it onto a replica set with the following:

```
mongorestore --host myReplSet/127.0.0.1:27020 --drop --username <username> --password <password>
```

The restore seems to work (it takes a minute or so and the output looks good) the database is created and all the collections are created but there is no data in the collections, they are all empty. What am I doing wrong?

For what it is worth, the local database is showing that it is 10 Gb big (I am not sure how big it was before the restore)

Comment: Everything seems legit. Did you check bson in dbpath files? Does it look like they contain expected data? Can you identify expected documents in the oplog. Is there anything unexpected in output of `rs.status()` or in the logfiles?

Comment: The BSON files in the dump look good, the content of the collections are binary so not really readable, but they contain data. rs.status() show one PRIMARY and 2 SECONDARY so no problem there. The oplog only contains index inserts???

Comment: OK, last information is weird, but I was thinking more about checking data directory of one of the replica set members. If there are corresponding data files there it is at least some sign that the data was actually restored.

Answer (score 5):

If anybody is facing the same issue. I used a replica set, and tried to do the Op's command. i.e

```
mongorestore --host myReplSet/mongo0.example.com:27020,mongo1.example.com:27012 --db <dbname> <folder_location>
```

Instead just go to the primary server and do this

```
mongorestore --port <if running on port other than 27017> --db <dbname> <location of dump>
```

This works for me, A possible explanation could be that whenever I write into the primary database, it is automatically copied over to my secondary databases. Hence no need to give any replica set address. This might work if you write in a secondary, I am not sure, haven't tried it. Maybe somebody else can throw a light on it.

Comment: your 'possible explanation' is the definition of the replica set -- so you're correct that writes to your primary get replicated to your secondary. But, if you're restoring a large dataset you might run into memory problems

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mongorestore version is the same version as the mongodb.

```
mongorestore --version

mongo --version
```

Same thing goes for the mongodump.

```
mongodump --version
```

They need to be the same or close enough versions.
These are issues that you will run into on a distributed system.
It will create the collections, but they will be empty if versions don't match.