# mongorestore failing because of DocTooLargeForCapped error

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to restore a collection like so:

`$ mongorestore --verbose --db MY_DB --collection MY_COLLECTION /path/to/MY_COLLECTION.bson --port 1234 --noOptionsRestore`

Here's the error output (timestamps removed):

```
using write concern: w='majority', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
checking for collection data in /path/to/MY_COLLECTION.bson
found metadata for collection at /path/to/MY_COLLECTION.metadata.json
reading metadata file from /path/to/MY_COLLECTION.metadata.json
skipping options restoration
restoring MY_DB.MY_COLLECTION from file /path/to/MY_COLLECTION.bson
file /path/to/MY_COLLECTION.bson is 241330 bytes
error: write to oplog failed: DocTooLargeForCapped document doesn't fit in capped collection. size: 116 storageSize:1206976512 @ 28575
error: write to oplog failed: DocTooLargeForCapped document doesn't fit in capped collection. size: 116 storageSize:1206976512 @ 28575
restoring indexes for collection MY_DB.MY_COLLECTION from metadata
Failed: restore error: MY_DB.MY_COLLECTION: error creating indexes for MY_DB.MY_COLLECTION: createIndex error: exception: write to oplog failed: DocTooLargeForCapped document doesn't fit in capped collection. size: 116 storageSize:1206976512 @ 28575
```

The result of the restore is a database and collection with correct names but no documents.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 running on Azure VM.

---

I just solved my own problem. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that I was using `mongod` on the replica set PRIMARY member.

Once I commented out the following line in `/etc/mongod.conf`, it worked without problems:
`replSet=REPL_SET_NAME` --> `#replSet=REPL_SET_NAME`

I assume passing the correct replica set name to the `mongorestore` command (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19835488/1447479)) could also work, but haven't tried that yet.